# using camel-stream in karaf

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I'm running a stock example route in karaf.  I know it's working because when I change stream:out to log:test, I can see the messages in the log every 5 seconds. However, I don't seem to get anything in the karaf console.  I also have camel-stream installed and don't see any errors in the log.   Should I expect to see  the stream:out  data when I run the karaf bin/client? thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" id="simple">
<route>
    <from uri="timer:simple?period=5000"/>
        <setBody>
            <simple>Hello World</simple>
        </setBody>
    <to uri="stream:out"/>
 </route>
</camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

I added the features info below.  I'm using karaf 2.2.9 now.  I tried it on 2.3.0:

```
karaf@root> features:list | grep stream
[installed  ] [2.9.4          ] camel-stream                             camel-2.9.4            
[uninstalled] [2.9.4          ] camel-xstream                         camel-2.9.4            
karaf@root> features:list | grep bluepr
[installed  ] [2.9.4          ] camel-blueprint                       camel-2.9.4            
[installed  ] [5.7.0          ] activemq-blueprint                    activemq-5.7.0         
karaf@root> ^D
```

I've tried the following as well:

```
service KARAF-service stop
cd /usr/local/karaf
rm -rf data/cache/*
service KARAF-service start
echo "features:install camel-blueprint camel-stream" | bin/client
cp /root/simple-camel-blueprint.xml  deploy/  && tail -f data/log/karaf.log
```

I get:

```
***deleted startup messages***
2012-12-01 14:56:42,166 | INFO  | - timer://simple | test                             | 64 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.9.4 | Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOnly, BodyType:String, Body:Hello World]
2012-12-01 14:56:47,134 | INFO  | - timer://simple | test                             | 64 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.9.4 | Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOnly, BodyType:String, Body:Hello World]
2012-12-01 14:56:52,135 | INFO  | - timer://simple | test                             | 64 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.9.4 | Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOnly, BodyType:String, Body:Hello World]
2012-12-01 14:56:57,135 | INFO  | - timer://simple | test                             | 64 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.9.4 | Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOnly, BodyType:String, Body:Hello World]
2012-12-01 14:57:02,135 | INFO  | - timer://simple | test                             | 64 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.9.4 | Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOnly, BodyType:String, Body:Hello World]
2012-12-01 14:57:07,136 | INFO  | - timer://simple | test                             | 64 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.9.4 | Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOnly, BodyType:String, Body:Hello World]
2012-12-01 14:57:12,135 | INFO  | - timer://simple | test                             | 64 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.9.4 | Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOnly, BodyType:String, Body:Hello World]
2012-12-01 14:57:17,135 | INFO  | - timer://simple | test                             | 64 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.9.4 | Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOnly, BodyType:String, Body:Hello World]
```

if I change the 'to uri'  from "log:test"  to "stream:out", then run bin/client I don't get anything.  is that a valid console out test?

I should add this too:

```
karaf@root> camel:route-info route3
Camel Route route3
    Camel Context: simple

Properties 
        id = route3
        parent = 7fcb9c0a

Statistics
    Exchanges Total: 5
    Exchanges Completed: 5
    Exchanges Failed: 0
    Min Processing Time: 1ms
    Max Processing Time: 5ms
    Mean Processing Time: 1ms
    Total Processing Time: 9ms
    Last Processing Time: 1ms
    Load Avg: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
    First Exchange Date: 2012-12-01 15:08:32
    Last Exchange Completed Date: 2012-12-01 15:08:52

Definition
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route id="route3" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <from uri="timer:simple?period=5000"/>
    <setBody id="setBody3">
        <simple>Hello World</simple>
    </setBody>
    <to uri="stream:out" id="to3"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Camel and Karaf version do you use?

And have you installed camel-stream feature? You would need to do that before installing and starting your own bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I learned a couple if interesting things while I was improving the quality of my  original post:)

Comment: I jsut retested using al the same versions that christian schneider used in his tutorial (http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/03/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+5+-+Running+Apache+Camel+integrations+in+OSGi).  I still can't get it to work.  is bin/client an invalid way to test stream:out?

Comment: Ah try with bin/karaf to start Karaf in the foreground as a shell. Then you have the output streams in the shell.

Comment: ha!  funny.  that was a tricky thing to search for.  thanks so  much!